# Помогите понять язык js

Tags: javascript

Всем привет!
Пытаюсь изучить js. Я вроде основы знаю, но ничего с этими знаниями сделать не могу. Читал Минника, Холлонда, честно сказать книга совсем не интересная, в ней нет подробностей и просто не понятно как дальше изучать.

Я вот к примеру знаю что есть методы свойства, функции. Вижу код, вижу там использование этого, но не понимаю, почему конкретно это свойство пишется перед скобками и т.д

Подскажите, может знаете книги где вот прям по максимуму практики.

Comment: Добавьте пример кода, чтобы было понятен контекст :)

Comment: Даже те, кто лет 10 пишут на JS всё равно не понимают, что это за чудо-юдо %))

Comment: "прям по максимуму практики" --- это либо сам  выдумай для себя задание и делай с постоянным поиском возникших проблем, либо на работу суперджуном

Comment: если нет идей что самому делать - вот минимум список https://github.com/florinpop17/app-ideas